# C# EWS ExchangeService: How do I know if it's authenticated?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I need to authenticate into EWS ExchangeService and when I use the code below I don't get any errors but I don't see any property on the service variable that says if its authenticated or not.  Even if I pass bad credentials it executes the same. No error and no properties saying if it's authenticated.

```
public static ExchangeService GetService()
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    service.Url = new Uri(@"https://someDomain.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("someEmail", "somePassword");
    return service;
}
```

I googled this extensively and didn't find anything helpful regarding authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Execute any operation that requires a live connection and see if it returns an error.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko.  Can you please define "operation"?  I executed the code above and got no error even with invalid credentials.

Comment: You need to do something that actually retrieves data from or pushed the data to the server. EWS library is lazy initialized - you don't do anything above that actually requires a connection to the server.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry.  that led to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dmity’s comment led to the solution.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Url = new Uri(@"https://luca1.cmtaegrs.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xcatest@cmtaegrs.com", "Cdaqt5e3swt5%");

//Add the operation as @Dmity suggested
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.Subject = "Interesting";
message.Body = "This is a test for authenticating.";
message.ToRecipients.Add("george.padvorac@crocodiledigital.net");

//See if we have the correct credentials
try
{
    message.Send();
    _credentials_good = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _credentials_good = false;
}
```